# Bundle installation error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have got some error during bundle install like that. I ran the command `/home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/bin/bundle install`

Here's the error details:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /home/circar
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler.rb:308:in `mkdir_p'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:287:in `create_bundle_path'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:54:in `run'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:18:in `install'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:107:in `run'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:158:in `install'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:7:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/gems/bundler-1.10.3/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/tanmay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@circarindia/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Environment

```
Bundler   1.10.3
Rubygems  2.1.11
Ruby      2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
GEM_HOME  /home/circar/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/ruby/2.0.0
GEM_PATH  
RVM       1.26.11 (master)
Git       1.7.9.5
```

Bundler settings:

```
without
  Set for your local app (/home/tanmay/amit_rails/circarindia/.bundle/config): "development:test"
disable_shared_gems
  Set for your local app (/home/tanmay/amit_rails/circarindia/.bundle/config): "1"
path
  Set for your local app (/home/tanmay/amit_rails/circarindia/.bundle/config): "/home/circar/.gem/ruby/2.0.0"
```

**UPDATE**
My bundle install run fine after these command.

rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/
  rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/,
  rm -rf .bundle/,
  rm -rf vendor/cache/,
  rm -rf Gemfile.lock,
But I don't understand these command.what is this command? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're logged in as the wrong user:  you're in `/home/tanmay` but the script is trying to write to the gems folder in `/home/circar`, because GEM_HOME is set to `/home/circar`.  Which user are you actually logged in as?  If the two users need to write to each others home folders then you can put them in a group together and make sure that the folders all have group write permissions.

Comment: But after  rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/
 rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ 
 rm -rf .bundle/
 rm -rf vendor/cache/
 rm -rf Gemfile.lock

Comment: after these comand run bundle install fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error somewhere in your Ruby or environment configuration. You are logged in as `tanmay` and your home directory is

```
/home/tanmay/
```

but the bundle tries to write to another user home path

```
/home/circar/
```

The `GEM_HOME` is incorrect.

```
GEM_HOME  /home/circar/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/ruby/2.0.0
```

Make sure you didn't copy/paste some configuration verbatim from a collegue. If you can't find the issue, you may want to remove and reinstall RVM.

Also make sure the PATH in your `.bash_profile`, `.profile` (or whatever env file you use) is correct and is not pointing to another home user directory.

Comment: but when I run some command in terminal then bundle install run fine.these command is  rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/
 rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ ,
 rm -rf .bundle/,
 rm -rf vendor/cache/,
 rm -rf Gemfile.lock ,

Comment: I didn't write any command. I explained what's wrong in your configuration. You will have to investigate your configuration.

Comment: My friend give me these command.But friend also don't know these command meaning.